# What did the English people during the Peasants' Revolt know about the Ciompi Revolt?

Tags: middle-ages, britain, italy, communication, rebellion

The Ciompi revolt started in Florence in June 1378 and the Peasants' Revolt started in England in May 1381, just three years later.

Did the news about Ciompi Revolt reach England in three years?

Did the ruling class in England gain some advantages over the rebels due to a previous knowledge about the Ciompi Revolt?

And what about the rebels? Did they know something about their Florentine mates (I would say "comrades")?

---

*Research (from OP's comment):*

*I had a look at [wikipedia page for Peasants' Revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasants%27_Revolt) and searched for the word "Ciompi" with no result. I was thinking that Simon Sudbury (the Archbishop of Canterbury during the Peasants' Revolt) could know something since he was member of the Catholic Church.*

Comment: no, it's a good question IMO (unless it can be trivially answered). I was asking so others know where to start.

Comment: Good, interesting question. Welcome to the site, and thank you for doing your research before you asked.

Comment: The elites, *maybe*, but the common folk I doubt because (1) there was no mass media; (2) communities at the time were very inward-looking; & (3) the language barrier. Many in the elite groups were fluent in Latin, so the language barrier would not be as much a factor -- if the elites cared to converse with each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It seems unlikely**. Especially with the commoners, it's hard to know for sure because "the rebels do not represent themselves for the  written record." ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100625154717/http://www.columbia.edu/~sc2298/Articles/The%20Writing%20Lesson%20of%201381.pdf)) I don't see any evidence that English peasants were aware of events on the continent in any way at all, nor that the elites followed this sort of thing.

**However**, this is not to say that the two revolts were totally unconnected. In the mid-to-late 14th century, [feudalism was in crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_of_the_Late_Middle_Ages) and [peasant revolts were widespread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_revolts_in_late-medieval_Europe) across late medieval Europe. The examples you ask about are just two of many, and may have had a number of **underlying causes in common**---famine, plague and war.

Comment: I haven't yet read [Richard Lachmann's book](https://b-ok.cc/book/673440/89d082) about early modern European elites, but if there was any direct communication between elites them about them revolts, that might be a good place to look.